# How to set Text data type in Entity for SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have this entity

```
[AutoIncrement(), PrimaryKey()]
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Guid { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
```

I am creating table in DB against this entity like this

```
connection.CreateTableAsync<MyEntity>();
```

This creates a table with a `varchar(140)` column against `Value` property. Now I would like to replace `varchar(140)` with `Text` datatype of SQLite.

What data type should I use in `Value` property so that it ends up at `Text` column in my SQLite DB table?

Comment: Why bother? SQLite will ignore the field length anyway.

Comment: @CL.Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: See [What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9) and [Datatypes In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on behalf of @CL [What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9)

> (9) What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR in SQLite?
>
> SQLite does not enforce the length of a VARCHAR. You can declare a
>   VARCHAR(10) and SQLite will be happy to let you put 500 characters in
>   it. And it will keep all 500 characters intact - it never truncates.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this will work:

```
[Column(TypeName = "Text")]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: This attribute is not available in Metro Apps. I can go with MaxLength